# How to make windows store app work with TLS 1.2?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, windows-store-apps

There is a windows store app 8.1 connected to a web service via WCF. Recently TLS 1.2 has been set at the server and as a result the app stopped working. Here is the exception

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://services.companyname.com This could be due to
>   the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with
>   HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of
>   the security binding between the client and the server.

Even a simple web request

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(SERVER_URL_PROD);
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

returns the following

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send.

So how to make windows store app work with TLS 1.2 ?

**Update**

The code above works in a console app (.NET 4.5) if

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But `ServicePointManager` is not available for Windows Store apps

**Update 2**

Moreover the code works in Windows Phone 8.1 where `ServicePointManager` is **not** available.

Comment: Good question. I too would like to add tls 1.2 to windows phone / tablet apps.

Comment: You could test your sever with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html to verify that supportet CipherSuits are available.

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with the TLS 1.2 issue for web applications, and as OP mentions, the simple solution for `System.Net.ServicePointManager` doesn't work in Windows Store apps.

The workaround is to use `Windows.Web.Http` instead of `System.Net.Http` as described in this [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/607bce52-3c07-4d6f-9692-ed540d5216ac/w81ctls12-support-in-windows-store-apps?forum=wpdevelop) posting.